# Where do I place XNA content pipeline references?

Tags: xna, xml, pipeline

I am relatively new to XNA, and have started to delve into the use of the content pipeline. I have already figured out that tricky issue of adding a game library containing classes for any type of .xml file I want to read.

Here's the issue. I am trying to handle the reading of all XML content through use of an XMLHandler object that uses the intermediate deserializer. Any time reading of such data is required, the appropriate method within this object would be called. So, as a simple example, something like this would occur when a character levels:

```
public Spell LevelUp(int levelAchived)
{
    XMLHandler.FindSkillsForLevel(levelAchived);
}
```

This method would then read the proper .xml file, sending back the spell for the character to learn. However, the `XMLHandler` is having issues even being created. I cannot get it to use the `using namespace` of `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline`. I get an error on my using statement in the `XMLHandler` class:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Serialization.Intermediate;
```

The error is a typical reference error:

> Type or namespace name "'Pipeline' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

I THINK this is because this namespace is already referenced in my game's content. I would really have no issue placing this object within my game's content (since that is ALL it deals with anyways), but the Content project does not seem capable of holding anything but content files.

In summary, I need to use the Intermediate Deserializer in my main project's logic, but, as far as I can make out, I can't safely reference the associated namespace for it outside of the game's content. I'm not a terribly well-versed programmer, so I may be just missing some big detail I've never learned here. How can I make this object accessible for all projects within the solution? I will gladly post more information if needed!

Comment: Any ContentImporter, ContentProcessor, or ContentWriters cannot be referenced at run time.

Answer (score 1):

Content pipeline can not be referenced from project using .NET Framework 4 Client Profile. You can change this in (Right click on project -> Properties -> Application -> Target framework).

But can't you use normal content pipeline to build your XMLs and then load them as normal content?

Answer (score 0):

The [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197604.aspx) for that namespace notes that it is only accessible from projects targeting Windows platforms. Double check that you are working with a standard XNA Game project and not an Xbox 360 one.

To check the target framework, select your project from the Solution Explorer then press **F4** to access the **Properties** panel for that project. **XNA Framework Platform** should be listed as one of the properties and should have the value **Windows** as Xbox 360 and Windows Phone 7 projects do not have complete access to the content pipeline.

**EDIT**

In what project is this troublemaker 'using' statement, a Content, Content Pipeline Extension or standard Game project? References to the Content.Pipeline assembly are only available to the first two. Whichever it is, select that project in the solution explorer, right click "References" then "Add reference..." Under the .NET tab, scroll down to the very bottom and, if it is an applicable project, you should see the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline assemblies.

Comment: I have done as you suggested and it is definitely listed as being a Windows platform project, and just in case, I also checked the game library containing all classes meant to be deserialized into. Also Windows, so I do not think this is the issue.

Comment: In what project is this troublemaker 'using' statement, a Content, Content Pipeline Extension or standard Game project? References to the Content.Pipeline assembly are only available to the first two. Whichever it is, select that project in the solution explorer, right click "References" then "Add reference..." Under the .NET tab, scroll down to the very bottom and, if it is an applicable project, you should see the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline assemblies.

Comment: @ZabbyWabby, hope that helped you out, if it did, mind accepting it as an answer? I'll edit that suggestion into the OP.

Comment: The used project is the main game project, and I already have added the reference you speak of. Currently, the content project uses this reference without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't realistically ask people to download the entire XNA development framework just to run your game.  And I'm pretty sure Microsoft won't allow you to just distribute the Content Pipeline DLLs willy nilly.

What you do to accomplish your goals depends on your answers to a couple of questions:

1. Do you need to be able to serialize data to XML at runtime, or is this purely so you can make a level editor and plug a bunch of data into XML files that are to be read by your game at runtime (your XMLHandler.FindSkillsForLevel suggests that the latter is your case).
2. Is it necessary for you to stream any data from a server that is meant to be deserialized, or can you assume it's all packaged in the game?
3. If you do indeed need runtime serialization, is it absolutely required that you use XML? You may find it easier to map your data to JSON, which is easier to read and a little faster to emit and parse for many cases.

If you are only using the XML for defining your game data (and making level editors for you to use, you should split your solution up into 4 projects: Engine, Game, Editor, Content. Don't think of Engine as this fancy thing, it's just the common code shared between Game and Editor (see [my answer here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/7474/3656)). Game contains game-specific code, all the presentation and special handling of level data and end-user UI. Engine can contain most of the code (AI, level logic, etc.) since you'll probably want to use the editor project as a catch-all for editing all sorts of data related to your game.

If you intend to stream XNB files to a desktop game, you may have to experiment with instantiating a ContentManager object using the [constructor that takes a string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195762.aspx). I haven't done this, so I don't know what the limitations are.

If you require runtime serialization/deserialization for playing your game outside of typical content pipeline use, you must handle your own serialization instead of relying on the content pipeline. The reflection API isn't too hard to use and understand, it's just tedious. And if you have to serialize your own stuff anyway, you may want to consider looking into [JSON](http://json.org/). It usually maps more intuitively to classes. A couple libraries to check out would be [LitJSON](http://litjson.sourceforge.net/) for something lightweight, and [JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) for something more featureful and robust.